# Characteristic zero lifts of a mod 4 cusp form

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $E$ be an non-CM elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ of conductor $N$ with a cyclic rational $4$-isogeny and let $f$ denote the corresponding cuspidal eigenform of level $N$. Let $E_4$ denote the Eisenstein series of weight $4$ and level $1$. Since $E_4 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, we have that $$fE_4 \equiv f \pmod 4.$$

The cusp form $fE_4$ cannot be an eigenform. My question is can there be a cuspidal eigenform $g$ of weight $6$ and level $N^{\prime}$ 
   such that $$ a_n(g) \equiv a_n(fE_4) \pmod 4, \ \mathrm{for\ all}\     
   \ (n,2NN^{\prime})=1, $$

or, in general, can there exists a cuspidal eigenform $g$ of weight $2k \ (k>1)$ of level $N^{\prime}$ such that
\begin{equation}
a_n(g) \equiv a_n(f) \pmod 4, \ \mathrm{for\ all}\  \  (n,2NN^{\prime})=1. 
\end{equation}

Comment: Why you ask the form g to have weight 2k? (if you think you are multiplying by E4, you should ask 2+4k). Clearly the form attached to the elliptic curve of conductor 11 has no newform of weight 4 (and level 11) congruent to it modulo 4 (check with sage). Also you can easily check that there is no form in weight 6 congruent to it modulo 4 either (sage again). The situation for prime powers is much more delicate than the primes one (where Deligne-Serre's theorem provides the eigenform g)

Comment: @Pacetti: Thanks. I agree with your example, where there is no weight 6 form that is congruent to fE_4 mod 4, and it answers the first part. However, the second part is still could be true. In the second part of the question, the reason for asking $g$ to be of weight 2k, not 2+4k, because in some specific examples there indeed exists such g's. Actually, I have forgotten to add that the $E$'s that I am considering are without CM and have a cyclic rational $4$-isogeny. So, I am editing the question.

Comment: Let me give you 2 comments on your question:
1) If a curve has a 4 isogeny, then for all primes p not dividing the conductor, a_p = p+1 modulo (4).
2) You are talking about elliptic curves with a 4 isogeny, then why don't you just ask whether there is a weight 4 form? (it is not a general question).
Still the answer is NO. Look at the curve 39a3 (which has a 4 torsion point), a_2=1 and a_3=-1. If you compute the space of weight 4 forms of level 39, there are no forms congruent to it.

Comment: Still, if you want a general theory, this case is extremely hard, since you are asking for representations at 2 (which are quite hard) + very small image (reducible modulo 2). I do not think you can find many general results in this direction. For big residual image + p>3 there are results on congruences modulo powers of p.

Comment: @Pacetti: Thank you. When I worked with 15a7 or 24a3, there were forms in weight 4 which are congruent to them. As you pointed out correctly, in some other cases none. That is why I am wondering in general, can there exists a cuspidal eigenform g of weight 2k, rather   than in specific weights, for which the congruence holds, which lead to this question.